# Can I still use JKS keystore to publish app to Google Play when I use Android Studio 4.0?

Tags: android-studio, google-play

I get the informtion *'It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore -destkeystore -deststoretype pkcs12" '* when I try to 'Generate Signed Bundle / APK ...'

I get the error *"Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption."* after I update my keystore to PKCS12 based the [artical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215400/how-to-solve-key-was-created-with-errors.).

Now I hope to give up PKCS12, can I still use  JKS keystore to publish app to Google Play when I use Android Studio 4.0?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59379375/2949966
IMO I still use the JKS format in my `build.gradle` instead of PKCS12 and I don't see any complaints when building with `assembleRelease`

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean I still need use JKS to sign my app in order to publish to Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really (still) go both ways.

You can use JKS keystores

And you can utilize, or move to PKCS12 format.