# Error when signing an apk with PKCS12 key

Tags: android, android-studio

When I tried to "Generate a signed bundle / APK" with Android Studio 4.0.1, I got the warning 'It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore -destkeystore -deststoretype pkcs12".

After converting my keystore to PKCS12 type, I got the following error :
*"Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption."*

I tried first to convert my JKS keystore, then to create a PKCS12 keystore from scratch. Both methods lead to the same error.

As described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465279/can-i-still-use-jks-keystore-to-publish-app-to-google-play-when-i-use-android-st/63871672#63871672), it seems we can currently go with both PKCS12 or JKS keystore types.
Actually, I'm publishing new app with JKS keystore type, but how long Google will permit it ? The warning message makes me doubt...

Does anyone find a solution to it ?
Thanks